# TypeError: yesterday.setHours is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm trying to query results from today and yesterday, however when I try to change the time to get the full two days I get the following error

> TypeError: yesterday.setHours is not a function

This is my function

```
exports.getReport = async (req ,res) => {
    const date = new Date();
    let today = date.setDate(date.getDate());
    let yesterday = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    yesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    today.setHours(23,59,59,999)
    
    const items = await Item.find({created: {$gte: yesterday, $lte: today}});
 
    res.json({items})
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [`Date.prototype.setDate` returns a timestamp and not a new `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const date = new Date();
    let today = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()));
    let yesterday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1));
    yesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    today.setHours(23,59,59,999)
```

find setDate return a timpestamp so typeof yesterday will be a number not a datetime check the above snippets

Comment: try it, and mark the answer as correct if it worked with you

Comment: `new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()))` is an inefficient way of copying a date, consider `new Date(+date)`.